# Skip bad files during AWS Redshift file load to S3 when using COPY command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

If I am loading files with this command 
COPY schema.table
FROM s3://bucket/folder/
It will stop loading all child objects if an error is reported and rollback the transaction. How do I skip the bad files? and load all files the don't have an issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by using `maxerror` parameter, which specifies that bad records are to be skipped. In the snippet below it is 100 (the errors are written to `stl_load_errors`):

```
copy venue from 's3://mybucket/venue'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=;aws_secret_access_key='
delimiter '\t'
maxerror as 100;
```